# SQL treat same column as a different column in the same table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I will try to explain the scenario first. 
There is a web app with a form that contains many fields. I want to add up two of these fields in order to compare with another value.

The table in the database contains a column called `dollar value`. All these fields have an `ID`. Therefore in order to retrieve the value from a field for a particular user, I call and ask for a particular `ID` for a particular user.

However, this table contains all the values for all the fields for all the users in the system. Meaning, each row in the table represents a value for a particular user for a particular field.

The question is, how can I add `field 1` with `field 2` and check it is equal to a value for all users.

**Example Table**

```
+====+==========+==============+
| ID | Field ID | Dollar Value |
+====+==========+==============+
|  1 |      123 |        35.00 |
+----+----------+--------------+
|  2 |      123 |        24.56 |
+----+----------+--------------+
|  3 |      543 |        10.00 |
+----+----------+--------------+
|  4 |      543 |        21.00 |
+----+----------+--------------+
```

I need to add `id 1` + `id 3` and check whether it is equal to a value.

Comment: This is not a good design.. but `SELECT SUM([Dollar Value]) FROM Table WHERE ID IN (1,2) and [Field ID] = 123` is a start - does that help?

Comment: It seems to be a bad design but I didn't create and I need to query the table. There are numerous rows in this table and I don't know the IDs for them. I only know the field IDs. So I'm not sure the above will be effective

Comment: The result I'm expecting is to display the IDs that match my query

Comment: @Camus Hello again! If you've found an answer here useful, please don't forget to accept one and vote it up. In doing so, you and they both get positive reputation and it helps future visitors to your question determine which answer is the most appropriate/helpful answer. If you've got any question about this, check out this link: [how-does-accepting-an-answer-work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple query like the one below to get the total of `id 1` + `id 3`:

```
SELECT SUM([Dollar Value])
FROM [Table]
WHERE ID IN(1, 3)
```

However, I don't know how you want to compare the total to the value, what comparison you want to perform (e.g. equal, greater or less than, etc), and what you want to do when the comparison is `true` or `false`.

If you want to compare in SQL, let's assume you want to give promotion if the total exceeds $100. You can do something like:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN SUM([Dollar Value]) > 100
            THEN 'Yes'
            ELSE 'No'
            END As Promotion
FROM [Table]
WHERE ID IN(1, 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you've posted so far (including recent comments), I think [GROUP BY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-group-by-transact-sql) and [CASE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql) should work for you.

For example (Note `LEFT JOIN` in the event you do not have a corresponding TargetValue in the 'other' table you mention exists):

```
SELECT tt.[FieldID], SUM(tt.[DollarValue]) AS 'CalculatedSUM', tv.TargetValue
        ,CASE WHEN SUM(tt.[DollarValue]) = tv.[TargetValue]
            THEN 'EqualValue'
        ELSE 'NotEqualValue'
        END AS 'ValueCheckTest'
FROM TestTable tt
LEFT JOIN TargetValue tv ON tt.FieldID = tv.FieldID
GROUP BY tt.[FieldID], tv.[TargetValue]
```

[image]

Here is the code I used to test with, and the results:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TestTable](
    [ID] [INT] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [FieldID] [INT],
    [DollarValue] [DECIMAL](19,2)
 CONSTRAINT [PK_TestTable_ID] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON)
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

--Create table with constraint FieldID + TargetValue (ex. 123,59.56) only allowed once. 
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TargetValue](
    [ID] [INT] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [FieldID] [INT],
    [TargetValue] [DECIMAL](19,2),
 CONSTRAINT [PK_TargetValue_ID] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON)
, CONSTRAINT [UQ_TargetValue] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED
(
    [FieldID], [TargetValue]
))  ON [PRIMARY]
GO


INSERT INTO [dbo].[TestTable]
SELECT '123','35.00' UNION ALL
SELECT '123','24.56' UNION ALL
SELECT '543','10.00' UNION ALL
SELECT '543','21.00' UNION ALL
SELECT '999','99.99'
GO

--maybe you have more than one TargetValue for a specific item
INSERT INTO [dbo].[TargetValue]
SELECT '123','59.56' UNION ALL
SELECT '543','150.00' UNION ALL
SELECT '543','59.56'
GO


SELECT tt.[FieldID], SUM(tt.[DollarValue]) AS 'CalculatedSUM', tv.TargetValue
        ,CASE WHEN SUM(tt.[DollarValue]) = tv.[TargetValue]
            THEN 'EqualValue'
        ELSE 'NotEqualValue'
        END AS 'ValueCheckTest'
FROM TestTable tt
LEFT JOIN TargetValue tv ON tt.FieldID = tv.FieldID
GROUP BY tt.[FieldID], tv.[TargetValue]


--DROP TABLE dbo.[TestTable]
--DROP TABLE dbo.[TargetValue]
```

Comment: It seems a good start but the other value will com from another table in similar fashion as the explanation I gave from the above table. However there will be no sum but only a value in a field.

Comment: @Camus Ok, I have updated Answer with additional information, which includes `LEFT JOIN` on 'another table'.